# How to turn on Bluetooth after turning it off in 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10 on a Dell XPS PC. Initially on Ubuntu the Bluetooth worked fine. I disabled Bluetooth for some reason using the switch in the settings UI and rebooted to Windows 10 and found the Bluetooth is gone in both OSs. After shutting down completely and restart the PC, I can use Bluetooth again in Windows. But in Ubuntu the "enable Bluetooth" switch is still gray and the message says

> No Bluetooth Found
>
> Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth

I've tried:

- installing the latest and previous kernels, but it didn't help.
- other walk around methods found, but all failed.

Result for `rfkill list`:

```
> rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Result for lspci:

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3ec2 (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e92
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f0)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Serial IO UART Controller #0
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a2c9
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SMBus Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
70:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0116
```

How can I turn the Bluetooth on?

---

Update: output of `lsusb`

```
[deleted]
```

Comment: Please add results for `lsusb`

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" the issued by stupidly re-installing Ubuntu.

---

PS: When booting from the USB PE, the Bluetooth configuration appears correctly. 
It seems to be a software bug that after disabling the Bluetooth under some circumstances you can never enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that reinstalling is not necessary.  I simply rebooted from my USB, opened the bluetooth system setting, found the device